# react chartjs 2 - Pie chart - Outlabels getting cropped

Tags: react-chartjs-2

Please find below screenshot for Pie chart. Please ignore black strips. If you see at the top, the labels are getting cut. I tried to add some space at the top but still these values are getting cropped. Can anyone suggests how can the chart gets resized depending upon options selected & I can show chart properly with all outlabels.
[image: Pie Chart]

This is SPFx solution using react. Below are more details:

"chart.js": "^2.7.3",
"chartjs-plugin-piechart-outlabels": "^0.1.4",
"react": "15.6.2",
"react-chartjs-2": "^2.7.4",
"react-dom": "15.6.2",

Thanks,
Sanjay